# How come my C++ STL regex_replace doesn't preserve Unicode?

Tags: c++, regex, macos, unicode, stl

How come this C++ STL `regex_replace()` scrambles the Japanese Unicode characters?

```
// assume #include <string> and <regex>
std::string sInput = R"(AA #-0233 338982-FFB /ADR1 2 これは私のテストです。)";
// remove numbers
std::string sOut = std::regex_replace(sInput, std::regex(R"([\d])"), "");
NSLog(@"%s",sOut.c_str());
```

In my XCode on Mac OSX get this result:

```
AA #- -FFB /ADR  „Åì„Çå„ÅØÁßÅ„ÅÆ„ÉÜ„Çπ„Éà„Åß„Åô„ÄÇ
```

Is that just because the `NSLog()` is not capable enough, or is this a deficiency in the STL `std::regex()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be the `NSLog()`. If we convert the sOut to an NSString and then output it, the problem goes away:

```
// assume #include <string> and <regex>
std::string sInput = R"(AA #-0233 338982-FFB /ADR1 2 これは私のテストです。)";
// remove numbers
std::string sOut = std::regex_replace(sInput, std::regex(R"([\d])"), "");
NSString *sTest = @(sOut.c_str());
//NSLog(@"%s",sOut.c_str());
NSLog(@"%@",sTest);
```

The output is:

```
AA #- -FFB /ADR  これは私のテストです。
```

The STL is handling Unicode just fine.